# How to address a workbook in vba for Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I´m trying to run a macro that works perfectly on a PC, but when trying to run the same macro on Mac I get the error `"1004"`; which says that the file can´t be found. 
I´m writing the address like this way:

```
Workbooks.Open("\Macintosh HD\Usuarios\carlosstephan\Dropbox\SCEN Const.\GastosyPagosSCEN.xlsm")
```

Does someone knows how to write it correct?.

I already tried with `"/"` instead of `"\"`, and it doesn´t works either.

The same error pops-up with this "with":

```
With Sheets("Gastos")

    .Range(“A8”, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear

End With
```

Where is the mistake?.

Answer (score 1):

Unless VBA on a Mac is different to Windows, change

```
.Range(“A8”, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
```

to

```
.Range("A8", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
```

The `“` and `”` characters are not the same as `"` and cannot be used as string delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

With the following VBA code you will know which is your separator:

```
Separator = Application.PathSeparator
```

or if you use the Inmediate window:

```
Debug.Print application.PathSeparator
```

Once you know the separator, substitute it in the Workbook path string and do not remove the spaces

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of Mac. I always have problems with getting VBA to run on Mac and Office 2016 has been a step backwards.

See
http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac017.htm

```
in 2011 it return a path like this :
Macintosh HD:Users:rdb:Desktop:YourFolder:
And in 2016  a path like this :
/Users/RDB/Desktop/YourFolder/
Reason is that in 2016 you must use the posix path in VBA codes
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still not working. I already tried with both examples, although my office is 2011. I erase also all the space in the names of folders and files. Still not working. where does the problem can be?.

Comment: Open the workbook normally in the UI. Then in vba debug.print activeworkbook.fullname. That will show you the path. As for the With error: Firstly qualify all objects fully. E.g. Activeworkbook.sheets ("gastos") Then if the error is on the With then you don't have a sheet of that name in that book. If on the next line then try Instead of "A8" .Range ("A8") although I don't think that'll make any difference.