# VBA on MAC Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

On PC this VBA runs perfectly, but on Mac, it is showing a printing error. how to correct the script so? Address is "Macintosh HD:Users:myname:Desktop:"

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportSheetsToPDFs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mywsname As String
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    mywsname = ws.Name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\Accounts\Desktop\" & mywsname & "_" & Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 19) & ".pdf", _
    openafterpublish:=False
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: `C:\Users\Accounts\Desktop\ ` isn't a path on a mac... is that the problem? The path you mention in the question would be written `/Users/myname/Desktop/`

Comment: I have tried to apply the path "Macintosh HD:Users:myname:Desktop:" but it looks like it is either something more complicated like a sandbox of Mac or I'm just not getting how to right properly the path in case of Mac. Once again - on PC it runs perfectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to address a workbook in vba for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944463/how-to-address-a-workbook-in-vba-for-mac)

Comment: Have tried as well  "Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/" but it still returns with the message "Error while printing".

Comment: Try dropping Macintosh HD. Just `/Users/myname/Desktop`

Comment: No, still the same error message

Comment: Ok - then I don't know :) is there any other info with the error? What line is erroring?

Comment: Found my mistake in one place left : instead of / Now it is running. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado now there is a new story :) the script is trying to print it on the printer, but not to save it as PDF. Give me some poison please :):):)

Comment: LOL. NOOOOOOOO!

Comment: It is funny, just restarted my mac and now it is working perfectly! Thank you again! It must be some magic :)